# Can I cast cost-less cards like Living End with Dream Halls?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I think the title is self-explaining :)

Can I cast cost-less cards like [Living End](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=113521) with [Dream Halls](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5105) by discarding a black card ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

[Living End](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Living%20End) has a mana cost of "unpayable".

[Dream Halls](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dream%20Halls) introduces an alternative cost of "discard a card that shares a color with the spell".

total cost
= (mana cost or alternative cost) + (additional costs and cost increases) - cost reductions
= discard a card that shares a color with the spell

> 117.6. Some mana costs contain no mana symbols. This represents an *unpayable cost*. [...]

> 117.6a [...] If an alternative cost is applied to an unpayable cost, including an effect that allows a player to cast a spell without paying its mana cost, the alternative cost may be paid.

---

Just in case there's any doubt, Living End is black.

> 204.2. An object with a color indicator is each color denoted by that color indicator.

(It had a characteristic-defining ability when it was printed, but it now has a color indicator. Characteristic-defining abilities work in all zones, so the answer would have been the same before the change.)

Comment: What is the colour indicator? The black frame?

Comment: @JonathanHobbs, A dot next to the types. Compare http://magiccards.info/fut/en/78.html and http://magiccards.info/mma/en/97.html